# Luatex Pattern matching %b

Tags: luatex

I have never tried to include Lua code in a document before so please be gentle.  I am after a pattern matching expression that will eventually take `(stuff1)->(stuff2)` and replace it with `!(stuff1)||(stuff2)` but baby steps first...

At the bottom of this page: [Programming In Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html) is a mention of a pattern for matching balanced strings.  After modifying some code I found on [site](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36272/14100) I decided to try the following:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\swap#1{%
    \directlua{%
      local s, _ = string.gsub("#1","%b()%b()","%2%1")
      tex.sprint(s)}
}

\begin{document}

\swap{(a)(b)}

\end{document}
```

Which does not work at all.  Can anyone explain what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The pattern `%b()%b()` does not contain captures, therefore `%1` and `%2` are not assigned.
You need an additional pair of parentheses

```
(%b())(%b())
```

The next problem is that the percent character is a comment character in TeX usually.
There are lots of ways to deal with this, the example below defines the string with the percent chars separately in a group where the catcode of the percent char is changed to the catcode of symbols like digits. See also package `luacode`.

Using `"#1"` is risky, `#1` might contain stuff that breaks the syntax of the string.
Therefore I have added `\luatexluaescapestring` (the name in LuaLaTeX for `\luaescapestring`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\begingroup
  \catcode`\%=12\relax
  \gdef\swapgsubargs{"(%b())(%b())","%2%1"}
\endgroup
\def\swap#1{%
  \directlua{%
    local s, _ = string.gsub("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}",\swapgsubargs)
    tex.sprint(s)%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\swap{(a)(b)}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thank you kindly, that helps to clear up a number of misunderstandings I had (although I'm sure that there are many more).  I'll have a look at the `luacode` package as well.

Comment: It is worth noting that `\string\%` is an easier way to get a percent character in a Lua string (it will be escaped by a backslash), so `\swapgsubargs` could be replaced by `"(\string\%b())(\string\%b())","\string\%2\string\%1"`, avoiding any catcode change.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch `\string\%` depends on the correct setting of `\escapechar`. Another alternative is LaTeX's `\@percentchar`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: You are right.