# Token replacement within a group

Tags: expl3, token-lists

A [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201921/tex-does-not-see-character-from-lua-string-manipulation?noredirect=1#comment470535_201921) below has clarified my problem, it has nothing to do with lua.  In the code snippet below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sops_format_set_expr:n #1 {
    \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl {A+\overline{(B+A)}}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {+}{\cup}
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\seval}{ m }{
    $\sops_format_set_expr:n {#1}$
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\seval{A+-(B+A)}

\end{document}
```

Is there a better way to perform the replacement `+` to `\cup`, than (for example) iterating over the string `A+\overline{(B+A)}` with `\tl_head`, checking for `head=group` along the way, and then piecing it back together?

---

---

**Background:** I'm making a little package to evaluate and format some set expressions.  I have code to do the evaluation, however printing is an issue.  I have code in lua that will evaluate an expression of the form `A+(B*C)` (with `+` interpreted as set union, and `*` interpreted as intersection) and print the resulting set.  Finding an appropriate way to handle complements, resulted in (what I felt was) the need to use pattern matching in lua to handle balanced delimiters properly.  As a result, part of the code does some string manipulation in lua, and spits it back to tex to be formatted.

**Question:**  The code below attempts to take a string of the form `-(<stuff>)`, and replace it with `\overline{(<stuff>)}` in tex. [See an earlier question of mine for reference.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71607/luatex-pattern-matching-b)

```
\begingroup
  \catcode`\%=12\relax
  \gdef\patmatch{"%-(%b())","\noexpand\\overline{%1}"}
\endgroup

\def\setcomp#1{%
  \directlua{
    local s, _ = string.gsub("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}",\patmatch)
    tex.sprint(s)
    %tex.sprint(-2,s) 
  }
}
```

I would like to have tex parse the resulting string (?) to replace `*` with `\cap` and `+` with `\cup`.  The issue is that in the replacement, tex does not recognize any `+` that is handled by lua in the string substitution above. The code below "accomplishes" the substitution:

```
\cs_new_protected:Npn \sops_format_set_expr:n #1 {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\setcomp{#1}}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {+}{\cup}
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\seval}{ m }{
    $\sops_format_set_expr:n {#1}$
}
```

When `\seval` is called on something like `\seval{A+-(B+A)}`, the `-(B+A)` is first handled by the string substitution and replaced with `\overline{(B+A)}`, when we have `A+\overline{(B+A)}` to be scanned for replacement of `+` with `\cup`.  The problem is that the first occurrence of `+` (the one not involved with the string substitution) is recognized, while the second one is not.  I blindly attempted to use `string.sprint(-2,s)` as commented in the first code block above, in which case the second `+` is recognized, but the macro is not.

As usual, my puny brain is unable to handle the intricacies of tex/lua catcode interaction.  Could someone please explain what the problem is, and how to fix it?  MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\begingroup
  \catcode`\%=12\relax
  \gdef\patmatch{"%-(%b())","\noexpand\\overline{%1}"}
\endgroup

\def\setcomp#1{%
  \directlua{
    local s, _ = string.gsub("\luatexluaescapestring{#1}",\patmatch)
    tex.sprint(s)
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new_protected:Npn \sops_format_set_expr:n #1 {
    \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {\setcomp{#1}}
    \tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl {+}{\cup}
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\seval}{ m }{
    $\sops_format_set_expr:n {#1}$
}
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\seval{A+-(B+A)}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\tl_replace` works on a “item” basis, not on a token basis. So if you have `{+}` it's seen not as `{`, `+` and `}` (three tokens) but as `{+}` (one item), and you can't reach the `+` inside a group `{}`.

Comment: @Manuel  Oh wow, I feel a little dumb now.  My whole question could have been about 5 lines long haha.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks btw.  Can you think of a better solution than iterating with `\tl_head`, handling a group as the head separately, and piecing back together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem is replacing, that `\tl_replace_…` doesn't work as you expect (everything inside `{}` is hid and can't be found). So the problematic line is only

```
\tl_replace_all:Nnn \l_tmpa_tl { + } { \cup }
```

### Option 1

Load `etoolbox` and use

```
\patchcmd \l_tmpa_tl { + } { \cup } { } { }
```

instead. The problem is that this doesn't work like `\tl_replace_all` but `\tl_replace_once`.

### Option 2

Load `l3regex` and substitute that line by

```
\regex_replace_all:nnN { \+ } { \c{cup} } \l_tmpa_tl
```

Comment: `regexpatch` offers `\xpatchcmd*` for that precise purpose. But since it's based on `l3regex`, it's simpler using it directly.